# How can I create an Array and let a Counter run through it to store values Created in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I hava a for loop which takes Inputs from a Json file and generates a html  Element and then just prints it out for testing, now i want to save each  element and at the end print it out.

I was planning on doing this with an Array which saves each for loop  Element and then saves it to the html file. Problem is i couldn´t find anything that would let me do that and i dont even know if thats the best solution.

> `players.online` gets an integer from 0-20 
> `players.sample[IO].id` gets a string which is then inserted into the URL from the  Element

**Code**

```
var IO;
var IOstring;
for (IO=0; IO < players.online; IO++) {
    //console.log(IO);
    IOstring = players.sample[IO].id;
    //console.log(IOstring)

    IOstring = '<img src="https://crafatar.com/avatars/"' + IOstring + '?overlay" alt="" width="32" height="32"></img>';
    //console.log(IOstring);
}
```

**Example Code**

```
var IO;
var IOstring;
for (IO=0; IO < 1; IO++) {
    //console.log(IO);
    IOstring = 2121e809-8c57-45dd-b4ed-921de8a20f1f;
    //console.log(IOstring)

    IOstring = '<img src="https://crafatar.com/avatars/"' + IOstring + '?overlay" alt="" width="32" height="32"></img>';
    //console.log(IOstring);
}
```

Comment: create a array `const array = []` then in your loop store the elemts at `array[i] = element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create array to store outputs

```
const output = [];
```

Instead of console.loging, push to the array

```
autput.push(IOstring)
```

And, at the and, you can log your array

```
console.log(output)
```

or create more complex single output using map method